# Recursive Binary tree insertion

Tags: c, recursion, tree, binary-tree, insertion

So I'm trying to insert a value into a binary tree using this recursive function:

```
void add(node* *hd, int v){
node* curr = *hd;
if(curr == NULL){
    curr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    curr->value = v;
}else{
    if(v < curr->value){
        add(&curr->left, v);
    }else{
        add(&curr->right, v);
    }
}
}
```

It doesn't seem to be working, and I just don't understand why I can't do something like this. How would I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to initilize the pointers, as they probably will be set to whatever you get when allocating space. Right now when you pass `add(&curr->left, v);` `curr->left` may not be a pointer somewhere but it is still not `NULL`;

```
void add(node* *hd, int v){
    node* curr = *hd;
    if(curr == NULL){
        curr = malloc(sizeof(node));
        curr->left = curr->right = NULL;
        curr->value = v;
        *hd = curr; // from Mohamed KALLEL
    }else{
        if(v < curr->value){
            add(&curr->left, v);
        }else{
            add(&curr->right, v);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that's right. your answer missed the fact to link the new node `curr` to the tree

Comment: Thank you, I understand now! I think it's supposed to be *hd = curr; though. But otherwise yes this is correct.

Comment: Don't you need to add `return;` to stop the recursion?

Comment: No as we are looking for a node which is empty to insert at, thus when we reach if(curr == NULL) we will allocate the memory, set the pointers and then the recursion stops(reaches the end of the function) as it no longer calls add() as it is the other branch which was not taken.

Answer (score 5):

Your new node is not being "hooked up" correctly, since you're just storing the pointer in the local variable `curr`, instead of writing it to `*hd` to change the caller's pointer.

Also, [don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Answer (score 2):

```
if(curr == NULL){
    curr = malloc(sizeof(node));
    curr->right = NULL;
    curr->left = NULL;  // From ks6g10 in order to initialize right and left to NULL
    curr->value = v;
    *hd = curr; // add this
}
```

BTW use `calloc` instead of `malloc`. it initializes your node memory to `0`

Comment: No point whatsoever in using `calloc()`; the only content it works for (the integer) is immediately overwritten. Note that `calloc()` can not be relied on to set pointers to `NULL` correctly.

Comment: yes you are right. In some platforms NULL is not 0. thx. answer updated

Answer (score 1):

Another way to add in the binary tree recursively can be done like this:

```
node *add(node *hd, int v) {
   node* curr = NULL;

   if(!hd){
      curr = malloc(sizeof(node));
      curr->value = v;
      curr->left = NULL;
      curr->right = NULL;
      return curr;
   }
   else {
     if(v < curr->value)
        curr->left = add(curr->left,v);
     else 
        curr->right = add(curr->right,v);  
  }
  return hd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize left and right pointers of your newly formed node with NULL and let your hd point to that node.

```
void add(node* *hd, int v){
node* curr = *hd;
if(curr == NULL){
    curr = malloc(sizeof(node));
    curr->value = v;
    curr->left=curr->right=NULL;
    *hd = curr;

}else{
    if(v < curr->value){
        add(&curr->left, v);
    }else{
        add(&curr->right, v);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
void insert(int data, node *&cur)
{
    if (cur == NULL)
    {
        cur = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        cur->data = data;
        cur->left = NULL;
        cur->right = NULL;              
    }
    else
    {
        if (data > cur->data)
        {
            insert(data, cur->right);
        }
        else
        {
            insert(data, cur->left);
        }
    }
}
```